# Admin>Sales>Orders list not showing

Tags: orders, sales-order, magento2.3

I'm using Magento 2.3.
How can I fix **Admin>Sales>Orders**?
The list is not showing.
I have **orders** but it's not showing.

Please help!!

Comment: Did you have run indexer command?

Comment: yes! showing We couldn't find any records. please help @SureshChikani

Answer (score 5):

You can check with the below option, maybe it will help to you.

Disable Asynchronous indexing from `Store > Configuration > Advance > Developer > Grid Settings`

***Note:** The Developer tab and options are only available in Developer mode.*

Updates: **Asynchronous order data processing.**

There can be times when intensive sales on a storefront occur at the same time that Magento is performing intensive order processing. You can configure Magento to distinguish these two traffic patterns on the database level to avoid conflicts between reading and writing operations in the corresponding tables. You can store and index order data asynchronously. Orders are placed in temporary storage and moved in bulk to the Order Management grid without any collisions. You can activate this option from Stores > Configuration > Advanced > Developer > Grid Settings > Asynchronous indexing.

You can get more information : [DevDocs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/performance-best-practices/configuration.html)

Comment: Thank you so much! Can you tell me the reason? but this is not more quicly for system?

Comment: You can just check after disabling this option. Is working or not.

Comment: yes, it is working. but why when i after enabled it not showing order list.

Comment: Check my updated answer.

Comment: Yes,but why i getting this issue? i dont understand , thank you!

Comment: do you know this problem , thankyou https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/259345/checkout-getting-no-such-entity-with-orderid