# Checkout getting No such entity with orderId =

Tags: checkout, magento2.3

I'm using `2.3`

But I don't know why when I place an Order I am getting `No such entity with orderId=`

How can I fix it?

look like this issue

[image]

update:

I check in chrome when i place an Order will showing

```
POST http://XXXX/rest/en/V1/carts/mine/payment-information 400 (Bad Request)

<response>
<message>
The consumer isn't authorized to access %resources.
</message>
<parameters>
<resources>self</resources>
</parameters>
<trace>
#0 public_html/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest/RequestValidator.php(68): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\RequestValidator->checkPermissions() #1 public_html/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest/InputParamsResolver.php(80): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\RequestValidator->validate() #2 public_html/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest/SynchronousRequestProcessor.php(85): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\InputParamsResolver->resolve() #3 public_html/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest.php(188): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\SynchronousRequestProcessor->process(Object(Magento\Framework\Webapi\Rest\Request\Proxy)) #4 public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http)) #5 public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array) #6 public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http)) #7 public_html/generated/code/Magento/Webapi/Controller/Rest/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array) #8 public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http)) #9 public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php(24): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch() #10 public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch() #11 public_html/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor)) #12 {main}
</trace>
</response>
```

Comment: which id do you get on error?

Comment: Check my updated. @magefms

Comment: you can debugging more using my answer

Comment: i'm trying, please wait @RakeshDonga

Comment: please check my new updated @magefms

Comment: please check my new updated @RakeshDonga

Comment: you can use Postnl Magento 2 extension?

Comment: May i know Postnl Magento 2 extension what helpful? @RakeshDonga

Comment: yes, i have search for you just tell me you use this extension?

Comment: no, i have no install it. @RakeshDonga

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88866/discussion-between-rakesh-donga-and-niceonelee).

Answer (score 5):

I had the same error before.But on Magento 2.2.8 
For my case the problem was only if you did a checkout as logged in customer and not as quest. 
The errors was coming from that file:

```
vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/ResourceModel/Order/Plugin/Authorization.php
```

function: after load

which is checking if the order is allowed for current customer.
For my occasion again I was getting that error because of a custom Module which was doing something with the invoice before the moment it should.
So I would start debugging my code to see when this function is called and which action is calling it.

I hope it helps someone.

Comment: How did you fixed this issue @vbak ? As I am facing the exact issue now

Answer (score 4):

If you receive the error message "**No such entity.**", "**No such entity with**" or "No such entity with **customerId,OrderId**" in Magento 2, the issue usually occurred when you try to load not existing object via Magento 2 Repository Class.

To debug this issue, please open the file

> vendor/magento/framework/Exception/NoSuchEntityException.php

and at the beginning of the `__construct` method temporary add debug backtrace code:

```
foreach (debug_backtrace() as $_stack) {
    echo ($_stack["file"] ? $_stack["file"] : '') . ':' .
        ($_stack["line"] ? $_stack["line"] : '') . ' - ' .
        ($_stack["function"] ? $_stack["function"] : '');
}
exit();
```

example:

```
public function __construct(Phrase $phrase = null, \Exception $cause = null, $code = 0)
 {

    foreach (debug_backtrace() as $_stack) {
        echo ($_stack["file"] ? $_stack["file"] : '') . ':' .
            ($_stack["line"] ? $_stack["line"] : '') . ' - ' .
            ($_stack["function"] ? $_stack["function"] : '');
     }
    exit();


    if ($phrase === null) {
        $phrase = new Phrase('No such entity.');
    }
    parent::__construct($phrase, $cause, $code);
 }
```

save the file and refresh the page.

You will see the debug backtrace that will allow you to define the issue source and you will get an idea how to fix it.

Usually third party Magento 2 extensions lead up to this problem, so you can override their code and add `try-catch` exception.

Don't forget to revert changes in **NoSuchEntityException.php** file after you're finished.

Comment: Hi, but this is new 2.3, why i need change the vendor file? thank you

Comment: just for debug after revert it

Comment: i chagned with you same and then text in checkout , it nothing showing about what. not working. please help,thank you!

Comment: @RakeshDonga this solution returns an error in NoSuchEntityException that 'index' is not defines (see https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/276051/magento-2-3-1-no-such-entity-with-customerid-backend-login-as-customer-logs)

Comment: Superb answer bro. Thanks. I have found which extension caused this. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Check **url_rewrite** table in your database, perform this **SQL query**

```
select * from url_rewrite where target_path like '%/category/orderId(in your error)%'
delete from url_rewrite where target_path like '%/category/orderId(in your error)%';

select * from url_rewrite where entity_type='category' and entity_id=orderId(in your error);
delete from url_rewrite where entity_type='category' and entity_id=orderId(in your error);
```

Comment: Check my updated

Comment: found this while searching on the internet, it might be helpful to you.   
**`SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
UPDATE `store` SET store_id = 0 WHERE code='admin';
UPDATE `store_group` SET group_id = 0 WHERE name='Default';
UPDATE `store_website` SET website_id = 0 WHERE code='admin';
UPDATE `customer_group` SET customer_group_id = 0 WHERE customer_group_code='NOT LOGGED IN';
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;`**

Comment: May i know what is this? this is about customer_group?