# Magento 2.3.1 : No such entity with customerId = Backend Login as Customer Logs page

Tags: customer, magento2.3, no-such-entity-exception

My English is not perfect sorry.
I am using Magento 2.3.1 and I saw this issue.
Admin > Reports > Customers > Login as Customer Logs

Login as Customer Logs
No such entity with customerId = 1

I added a picture. Have any idea?
Thank you so much.
https://prnt.sc/nsza9d

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this error before.  You have some orphan data.

In our case we had to delete addresses that belonged to customers that no longer existed.

```sql
DELETE FROM `customer_address_entity` WHERE `parent_id` NOT IN (SELECT `entity_id` FROM `customer_entity`)
```

Yours relates to log

So try this

```sql
DELETE FROM `customer_log` WHERE `customer_id` NOT IN (SELECT `entity_id` FROM `customer_entity`)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My website not published yet. I have 2 customers for trials. And I deleted now. But still the same.

Comment: Hi again, I found this solution.
https://magefan.com/blog/no-such-entity-fix-for-magento-2
And I saw this issue related to mageplaza login as customer extension. I did disable. Now no issue. Thank you so much.

Comment: @EK. this magefan.com/blog/no-such-entity-fix-for-magento-2 looks like is not working with Magento 2.3 (https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/291424/magento-2-3-the-error-evolution-from-entity-customerid-to-index-file-undefi), it's making another exception, how did you get it work?