# Magento 2.3 : "the error evolution"_from entity CustomerId= to index file Undefined

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, exception, file, no-such-entity-exception

I have a problem with Magento 2.3, when I use X-debug on the checkout part, I have the following exception :

> **Exception has occured.**
>    Magento\framework\Exception\NosuchEntityException: No such entity with customerId =

So far nothing that much surprising, basic so detail exception from Magento so looking for solution and hop a solution : https://magefan.com/blog/no-such-entity-fix-for-magento-2 (or more exactly as solution to see where is the problem)

So ok let add :

```php
 foreach (debug_backtrace() as $_stack) {
        echo ($_stack["file"] ? $_stack["file"] : '') . ':' .
            ($_stack["line"] ? $_stack["line"] : '') . ' - ' .
            ($_stack["function"] ? $_stack["function"] : '');
     }
    exit();
```

And TaDa :

> **Exception has occured.**   Exception: Notice: Undefined index: file in
>   /var/www/mywebsite/magento/framework/Exception/NoSuchEntityException.php
>   on line 37

So of course this come from the file modified according to https://magefan.com/blog/no-such-entity-fix-for-magento-2 and line 37 is

```php
        echo ($_stack["file"] ? $_stack["file"] : '') . ':' .
```

Appearing that file is not a defined index, but then what should I do instead ? 
Someone has a solution to solve it ?

PS: in case of minus please let me know why so that I can improve my post

Answer (score 0):

Why not using this:

```
 var_dump(debug_backtrace());
```

*debug_backtrace()* is a native php function.
https://www.php.net/debug_backtrace