# Email Template order id in guest checkout

Tags: magento-2.1, magento2.3, email-templates, order-email, guest-checkout

I have create a new email template in admin and linked a phtml template in content like below.

```
{{block class='Sketchshot\\EmailTemplate\\Block\\Index\\Index' 
area='frontend' template='Sketchshot_EmailTemplate::email/logo.phtml'}}
```

In my **logo.phtml**

```
<?php 
   $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

   $storeInformation = $objectManager->create('Magento\Store\Model\Information');
   $storeManager = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
   $baseUrl = $storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl();

   $store = $objectManager->create('Magento\Store\Model\Store');

   $storeInfo = $storeInformation->getStoreInformationObject($store);
   $storeName = $storeInfo->getName();
   $street_line1 = $storeInfo->getData('street_line1');
   $city = $storeInfo->getData('city');

   $postcode = $storeInfo->getData('postcode');
   $variable = $objectManager->create('Magento\Variable\Model\Variable');

   $value = $variable->loadByCode('formattedShippingAddress')->getPlainValue();

   $orderId = $this->orderId();

   $time = time();
   $check = $time+date("Z",$time);
   $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
   $orders = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->load($orderId);

    $custLastName= $orders->getCustomerLastname();
    $custFirstName= $orders->getCustomerFirstname();
    $billingAddress = $orders->getBillingAddress();
    $shippingAddress = $orders->getShippingAddress();
    $orderItems = $orders->getAllItems();
    $number = $orders->getGrandTotal();
    $invoice_id = '';
?>
```

I can able to get order Id using this code `$orderId = $this->orderId();` when ordered as customer. But when I try to order as guest I can't place order I get below issue in exception log.

```
[2020-06-05 13:47:38] main.CRITICAL: No such entity with orderId =  {"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\Exception\\NoSuchEntityException(code: 0): No such entity with orderId =  at /home/project/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Exception/NoSuchEntityException.php:50)"} []
```

Comment: your above error is not proper error.So put this code --- https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/259371/85907 and debug