# new orders are not showing in orders grid

Tags: magento2, orders, sales-order, order-grid

I upgraded to 2.3.1

I am using only PayPal as a payment method.

new orders are not showing in the orders grid in Admin > Sales > Orders

when I check PayPal summary I can find the invoice number so it is created in Magento but not showing in the grid

I already tried to change

Store > Configuration > Advance > Developer > Grid Settings

Enable / Disable, flush cache, reindex,  but not working

update: When I check `sales_invoice` there is no recent invoice! But in PayPal summary I have the invoice number and items!

Comment: any fix suggestion @anas-mansuri ? Anas Mansuri

Comment: Check this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/259307/adminsalesorders-list-not-showing
Vote up if it solved

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, I already tried this fix but not worked for me,

Comment: Are the orders in the database at all? In `sales_order`? The grid gets its information from `sales_order_grid`?

Comment: I can't find orders in sales_order_* , but PayPal give me the invoice number wich is not existing in the invoice table

Answer (score 2):

Clear the `var` and `generated` folders and run cron

```
rm -rf var/*    
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
rm -rf var/*
rm -rf generated/*
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cron:run
php bin/magento cron:run
```

Comment: Hi @CDzWebDev. Did you check this?

Comment: Hi @MSA I am working on it :)

Comment: unfortunately this is not working

Comment: Did you try to sort by date?

Comment: Yes I tried sorting by date

Comment: Is it working now?

Comment: No, Not working

Comment: It not related cache or cron , because, order grid does not manage under cache system of magento especailly admin orders .

Comment: The cronjobs weren't running.. so that gave me the hint