# New orders are not showing in the orders grid but payment received

Tags: magento2, orders, sales-order, paypal, order-grid

I upgraded from Magento 2.2.5 to 2.3.1

I am using only PayPal as a payment method.

new orders are not showing in the orders grid in Admin > Sales > Orders and emails are not sent !!

when I check PayPal summary I can find the invoice number so it is created in Magento but not showing in the grid

I already tried to change

> Store > Configuration > Advance > Developer > Grid Settings

Enable / Disable, flush cache, reindex, but not working

When I check sales_invoice and sales_order tables there is no recent invoice !!but in PayPal summary I have the invoice number and items !!

Any fix please.

Comment: Anything in exception logs?

Comment: [2019-06-17 10:46:31] main.CRITICAL: The "3000000098" order ID is incorrect. Verify the ID and try again. {"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: 0): The \"3000000098\" order ID is incorrect. Verify the ID and try again. at /home/public_html/vendor/magento/module-paypal/Model/Ipn.php:143)"} []

Comment: If 3000000098 is missing from your admin grid that's confirming you are missing the order data. PayPal is contacting the site about an order and the site doesn't know what the order is

Comment: Yes, also in database I can not find the order !!

Comment: Nothing else in log just before this?

Comment: [2019-06-15 11:11:27] main.CRITICAL: Unable to retrieve deployment version of static files from the file system. {"exception":"[object] (UnexpectedValueException(code: 0): Unable to retrieve deployment version of static files from the file system. at /home/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/View/Deployment/Version.php:88)"} []

Comment: [2019-06-15 11:13:10] main.CRITICAL: The contents from the "/home/public_html/pub/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto/en_GB/mage/requirejs/mixins.min.js" file can't be read. Warning!file_get_contents(/home/public_html/pub/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto/en_GB/mage/requirejs/mixins.min.js): failed to open stream: No such file or directory {"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\Exception\\FileSystemException(code: 0): The contents from the \"/home/public_html/pub/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto/en_GB/mage/requirejs/mixins.min.js\" file can't be read.

Comment: Warning!file_get_contents(/home/public_html/pub/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto/en_GB/mage/requirejs/mixins.min.js): failed to open stream: No such file or directory at /home/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Filesystem/Driver/File.php:151)"} []

Comment: Does this answer your question? [new orders are not showing in orders grid](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/278460/new-orders-are-not-showing-in-orders-grid)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a quick skype conversation we have noticed that a file was corrupt within the `Magento_Inventory` model.

We have removed the directory `vendor/magento/module-inventory` and run `composer update`. The dependency compiler (`php bin/magento setup:di:compile`) runs without error now.

Not confirmed yet that this was the issue. We will update.

Comment: Thank you @CompactCode, the best Magento company I ever I collaborated with.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if cron is running or not. Sales order grid updates by cron only.